# Location of a directory created with mkdir in PHP

Tags: php

I've been trying a bunch of stuff with creating zips and files and whatnot with php, and it's safe to say I messed up quite a few times...

My most recent:

```
$tmpp = tempnam('../test','mod');
echo "<br/>"."<br/>".basename($tmpp).'<br/>'."<br/>".$tmpp.'<br/>'."<br/>";
echo mkdir(basename('../test/'.$tmpp));
```

I meant to do

```
$tmpp = tempnam('../test','mod');
echo "<br/>"."<br/>".basename($tmpp).'<br/>'."<br/>".$tmpp.'<br/>'."<br/>";
echo mkdir('../test/'.basename($tmpp));
```

Oh well though, mistake is made. Where is this just created directory? How can I see all the other files and directories and things as well as the tmp folder?

edit: long story short: I've created a bunch of files and directories that I can't account for and I want to be able to find them on clean then off my server. How can I view ALL the files on my server, including in the tmp folder?

Comment: Can you plz make your question more clear ?

Comment: You probably don't want to view all the files on your server. This looks like a question for Server Fault or Unix&Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the return value of mkdir? "false" ?

If so, I think maybe you need check your write permisson of the account which execute this php script.